# Limit and interior points of a set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

A general definition of limit point is the following:

> A point $z_0$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(z_0)$ of $z_0$ intersects the set $A$ at some point other than $z_0$.

Now a definition $\epsilon$-neighborhood:

> An $\epsilon$-neighborhood of point $z_0$, denoted $V_{\epsilon}(z_0)$, is the set of all points $z$ for which $|z-z_0|<\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon$. That is, $V_{\epsilon}(z_0) = \{z \in \mathbb R\ : |z-z_0| < \epsilon\}$

Now consider the set $A$ formed by elements of the sequence $z_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$, which has limit point $z=0$.

$$A = \{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb N\}$$

Why $z=1$ could not be a limit point of $A$? Does it mean that a limit point does not belong to the set itself? Is there another definition of interior point so that its neighborhood contains only points in $A$. In that case, which are the interior points of $A$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point $1$ is not a limit point of the set, because there is a neighbourhood of $1$ such that the only point in the set in that neighbourhood is $1$. Use, for example, the interval $(0.9,1.1)$.

In fact no point *in the set* is a limit point of the set. Around the point $\frac{1}{n}$, you can put the neighbourhood $(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{4^n},\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{4^n})$ that contains no point of our set other than $\frac{1}{n}$.

To show that $0$ is a limit point of our set, take an open interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ about $0$, where $\epsilon$ is small (possibly *very* small) positive. There is an integer $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}\lt \epsilon$. Then every point $\frac{1}{n}$ in our set with $n\ge N$ is in that neighbourhood.

So every open neighbourhood of $0$ contains a point of our set, indeed infinitely many points of our set.

Much more informally, we can get arbitrarily close to $0$ from within our set.

A limit point of a set may or may not belong to the set. For example, let $S=(0,1)$, that is, all real numbers $x$ such that $0\lt x\lt 1$.  The number $1$ is a limit point of $S$, and is not in $S$.

Let $T=[0,1]$. The point $1$ is a limit point of $T$ and is in $T$.

Comment: Nicolas  thanks for reply,then why is $0$ limit point?

Comment: I will add answer to that in the post, it is easier to type there!

Comment: so  for point to be  limit point,it means that it should contain at least one element of set,besides this point?at least means  that just one point is enough?

Comment: for example interval $(-0.5,0.5)$

Comment: @dato Every neighborhood of a limit point has to contain infinitely many points of the set.  Not 1, or 2, but infinitely many.  That is why 1 is not a limit point, and 1/2 is not a limit point, etc.

Comment: Let $S$ be a set, and $a$ a point, **not necessarily** in $S$. We say $a$ is a limit point of $S$ if every neighbourhood of $a$ contains a point of $S$ other than $a$. (If $a$ is not in $S$, we don't need to add that last bit, but for generality we must.)

Comment: @dato Well, you already wroe that ni the definition of limit point in your post: "contains points,other then $z_0$ of set$.

Comment: but  ok we take number $0$,it's  neighborhood  let take $(-0.5,0.5)$,does it contains $1$?

Comment: At least one is enough because of the for **every** neighbourhood. Saying there is at least one for every neighbourhood implies that there are actually infinitely many in every neighbourhoodd.

Comment: also does choosing of neighborhood depend on us?or we are choosing neighborhood as we like?

Comment: The neighbourhood you mentioned does not contain $1$, but it contains, for example, $\frac{1}{7}$. So it contains *some* element of our set, indeed infinitely many elements of our set. Draw a picture, long space between $0$ and $1$. Put dots at $\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3}$, and so on.

Comment: thanks for helo,please one more question what about interior point?

Comment: **Whatever** neighbourhood we are challenged with, we must be able to show there is a point of our set (other than the limit point, if that's in the set) in the neighbourhood. So the neighbourhood is not our choice.

Comment: A point $a\in S$ is an interior point of $S$ if there is some neighbourhood of $a$ which is entirely in $S$.

Comment: for example  is $1/4$ interior?because $1/3$ and  $1/5$ are in the set?

Comment: @ André Nicolas could   you answer to my last question?thanks in advance

Comment: yes yes i have understood limit point thanks in advance,i need help in interior points

Comment: I defined interior point in an earlier comment. No point in our set $S=\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is an interior point of the set. For if $p$ is one of these, then any neighbourhood of $p$ contains points not in $S$.

Answer (score 1):

For a limit point $x$ of a set $S$, every neighborhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $S$.  In your example, not every neighborhood of 1 contains infinitely many points of the set.  For example, the open ball centered at 1 with radius 1/4 contains only 1.

Comment: could you clarify with numbers?

Comment: So the set in question is $S = \{1, 1/2, 1/3, ...\}$.  If we take the open ball centered at 1 with radius 1/4, this is the same as the interval $I = (3/4, 5/4)$.  But $I \cap S = \{1\}$, and so does not contain infinitely many points of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

We consider the set $E=\{1,\frac12,\frac13,\ldots\}$ in $\mathbb R$. No point of $E$ is an interior point of $E$. $1$ is not a limit point of $E$ because its $\frac12$-neighbourhood does not contain any point of the set other than itself. But $0$ is a limit point of $E$ because for every $\epsilon >0$, there is a positive integer $k$ so that $\frac1k <\epsilon$, and then $\frac1k$ is a point in $E$ that is not $0$ itself ($\frac1k$ is in its $\epsilon$-neighbourhood).

A limit point of a set may or may not belong to the set. An example of a limit point of a set which belongs to the set is the point $1$ which is a limit point of $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb R$. An example of a limit point of a set which does not belong to the set is the point $1$ which is a limit point of the set $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$.